# Using strlen to strikeout specified words in string

Tags: c++, string

Using the following function, I am able to pass in two strings (char *hide, char *phrase). The *phrase is the overall string and * hide is what words (can be repeated) have to be censored by replacing all letters in the word with '*'. It currently works so that it goes on to find the first letter of the *hide, then the second letter of the *hide word despite it not being next to each other in the string eg.

```
*phrase = 'hello my name is'

*hide = 'lame'

result = 'he*lo my n*** is'

    {
        int i, j=0;
        int lengthPhrase = strlen(phrase);
        int lengthCensor = strlen(hide);
        for (i = 0; i < lengthPhrase; i++) {
            if (phrase[i] == hide[j]) {
                phrase[i] = '*';
                j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Where is the issue so that it works correctly by striking out the whole words??

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Two things: In C++ string literals are constant arrays of characters. Attempting to modify one (through a pointer) leads to *undefined behavior*. The second thing is that if you're really programming in C++ you should be using `std::string`, which solves the previous problem.

Comment: You're also using multi-character literals by mistake. Presumably because you couldn't get the string literal assignment to work then you randomly changed things until it compiled; sadly, this process of "programming by guessing" was proven terrible by the fact that the end result is wrong. Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: Use `std::search` to find matches for the target string.

Comment: What does your question mean ? Do you mean to strike out the word "lame" from phrase or strikeout the chars of "lame" in phrase ? Show us an example of what you really want. The code isn't helping much.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't seem to understand your question, I thought of making a function for you to see if this is what you're looking for:

```
    string phrase = "hello my name is"

    string hide = "lame"    

    //strikeout function
    void strikeout(string phrase, string hide)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hide.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < phrase.size(); j++)
            {
                if (hide[i] == phrase[j])
                {
                    phrase[j] = '*';
                }
            }
        }
        cout << phrase << endl;
    }
```

Output based on your testcase: "h***o *y n*** is"